# How to move specific rows from an original table to a new table?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

In SAS, I have a table that have 1000 rows. I am trying to separate that table into two tables. Row1-500 to Table A and row501-100 to table B. What is the code that can do this function. Thank you all for helping!

I am searching the code online and cannot get anything on google, help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far. https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2020/07/23/splitting-a-data-set-into-smaller-data-sets/

Answer (score 2):

The DATA statement lists the output tables of the step.  An `OUTPUT` statement explicitly sends a row to each of the output tables.  An explicit `OUTPUT <target> ... <target-k> statement` sends records to the specified tables only.  The automatic implicit loop index variable `_n_` can act as a row counter when a single data set is being read with `SET`.

Try

```
data want1 want2;
  set have;
  if _n_ <= 500 then output want1; else output want2;
run;
```

However, you may be better served by creating a categorical variable that can be used later in `WHERE` or `BY` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the set options will help.Try `firstobs=` and `obs=` to choose the rows you want.
Here is how to use them:

```
data want1;
  set have(obs=500);
run;
data want2;
  set have(firstobs=501 obs=1000);
run;
```